# Jersey @PreMatching and name binding in 1 provider

Tags: java, rest, filter, jersey-2.0, name-binding

I need to implement a Jersey filter `(ContainerRequestFilter)` that needs to be called during `pre-matching` phase but only apply to some resources.

The `pre-matching` part can be done by annotating the class with the `@PreMatching` annotation and the `"apply to some"` functionality through Jersey's `NameBinding` mechanism.

What I would need it to combine the 2 features in 1 provider; now I'm pretty sure that this cannot be done since to me it seems contradictory (filter will be called before we can check if a given class is annotated) but still I want to be 100% sure of this since I would be skipping 1 step in the Jersey lifecycle and thus reducing the response time.

I'm using Jersey 2.6

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can't specifically answer wether it is possible or not, but I wanted to comment on the "skipping 1 step to reduce response time": I would say you won't even need to consider that at all at this point. Aim at making your code easy to read and to understand (perhaps it will be a better structure to split in both filter and some feature class and share common code anyway).

IF you run into performance problems/long response times during test/early deploy, profile your app and see what actually takes time and focus on those areas first. I'm very confident the time is not spent where you think it is, and I'll buy you a beer if it actually ends up being this extra step in the lifecycle causing your (any) performance problems.

Comment: Hi thanks for your input, I guess you are right it won't change much the response time, I asked the question mainly out of curiosity to be sure I understood this part of Jersey's lifecycle